# Getting NameError in django views.py , as NameError : name 'edit_load_table' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

```
name 'edit_load_table' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_load/N193
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'edit_load_table' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Users\Virti Parekh\projects\try\total_load\views.py, line 45, in edit_load
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Virti Parekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Virti Parekh\\projects\\try',
 'C:\\Users\\Virti '
 'Parekh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Virti Parekh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Virti Parekh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Virti Parekh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\Virti '
 'Parekh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 05 Dec 2020 19:04:19 +0000
```

I want to fetch particular empId data from table "edit_load_table". When I m clicking load details (as an anchor tag) it will fetch the data of particular empId data in tabular format.

This is my models.py code

```
class facultyload(models.Model):
    empId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_load = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empId

class edit_load_table(models.Model):
    empId = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject_abv = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subject_load = models.IntegerField()
    subject_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    id_key = models.IntegerField()
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.empId
```

This is my views.py code

```
def edit_load(request, empId):
    editload = edit_load_table.objects.get(str=empId)  
    return render(request,"edit_load.html",{'editload':editload})
```

As my empId contains both letters and numbers so I gave str=empId.
In my urls.py I have pass

```
path('edit_load/<str:empId>',views.edit_load)
```

Anyone can help me to solve this error as I m new to Django and python. Thank You!

```
edit_load.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Faculty's Subject wise Load</title>

    {% load static %} 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/style-main.css' %}"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
    
</head>
<body>
        <div class="center-div">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>Faculty List with their load</h1>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sr No.</th>
                            <th>Subject Name</th>
                            <th>Subject Load</th>
                            <th>Subject Type</th>
                            <th>Semester</th>
                            <th colspan="2">operation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                   
                    <tbody>
                        {% for faculty_load in edit_load %}

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{faculty_load.id_key}}</td>
                                    <td>{{faculty_load.subject_abv}}</td>
                                    <td>{{faculty_load.subject_load}}</td>
                                    <td>{{faculty_load.subject_type}}</td>
                                    <td>{{faculty_load.semester}}</td>
                                    <td><a href="/facultysubjectDetails/{{faculty_load.id}}" ><span class="btn btn-success">Edit</span></a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/deletedetails/{{faculty_load.id}}" ><span class="btn btn-danger">Delete</span></a></td>
                                </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

piece of code from where I called edit_load.html file

```
<td><a href="/edit_load/{{loads.empId}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="load details"  name="load details" method="GET">Load Details</a></td>
```

Comment: Did you import your models from `views.py` ?

Comment: Not str=empId should be empId=empId in object.get

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Yes I have imported models in my views.py, now I am redirecting to my page but it is not showing me the result .

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło I have corrected as you mentioned also I have applied the "filter(empId=empId)" method function to retrieve more than one record but it redirecting to my page without any error but still, it is not displaying or fetching the records. Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: @VirtiParekh  if `objects.get(...)` does not find the element then it will raise an exception. As you said that no error is shown, it can be just an issue with the template. Can you add the html code where you show the `edit_load` ?. Also keep in mind that `filter()` returns a list so you would have to get the first element, something like `èdit_table[0]`

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I added HTML code also can you please check, thank you. Also, I added the piece of code where I called HTML file (edit_load.html).

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Thank you For the help! I solved this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above error also solved the error which I have mentioned in my comments. I changed some parts of my code.
In views.py I have used views to return multiple data references from one ID.

views.py

```
def edit_load(request, empId):
    parent = edit_load_table.objects.filter(empId=empId)
    context = {'parent':parent}
    return render(request,"edit_load.html",context)
```

In my HTML file earlier I have used this {% for faculty_load in edit_load %} which is wrong and it is giving me an error after I got that we have to pass the value which I have mentioned in context.

```
{% for loads in parent %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{loads.subject_abv}}</td>
                                        <td>{{loads.subject_load}}</td>
                                        <td>{{loads.subject_type}}</td>
                                        <td><a href="/editfacultydetails/{{loads.id}}" ><span class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</span></a></td>
                                        <td><a href="/deletefacultydetails/{{loads.id}}" ><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</span></a></td>
                                    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope my answer will be useful. And also in comments the suggestion were mentioned is useful for me . Thank you.